# Remove fluctuations in height of the ul whilst under a css transition

Tags: html, css, sass

The following code is used to define the style of a side navigation which I use. And it works great without any transitions.

*SCSS Code and working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/mvpzf5Lf/3/)*

```
.side-nav{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 15vh;

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: blue;
    @include border-radius(20px, 0, 20px, 0);
    width: 1cm !important;
  }

  li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: 1cm;

    span {
      white-space: pre;

      &.short {
        color: black;
        display: block;
      }

      &.long {
        display: none;
        color: white;
      }
    }

    &:hover {
      right:200%;
      width: 3cm;
      @include border-radius(20px, 0, 20px, 0);
      border-style: solid;
      border-right-style: none;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: blue;
      background: red;
      margin: -3px 0;

      span {
        &.short {
          display: none;
        }

        &.long {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

However, when you add the transition code, as you will see if you go on the JSFiddle, the height of the `ul` fluctuates.

*SCSS Code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/mvpzf5Lf/4/) which demonstrates problem*

```
.side-nav{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 15vh;

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: blue;
    @include border-radius(20px, 0, 20px, 0);
    width: 1cm !important;
  }

  li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: 1cm;
        @include transition(all 1s);

    span {
      white-space: pre;

      &.short {
        color: black;
        display: block;
      }

      &.long {
        display: none;
        color: white;
      }
    }

    &:hover {
          @include transition(all 1s);
      right:200%;
      width: 3cm;
      @include border-radius(20px, 0, 20px, 0);
      border-style: solid;
      border-right-style: none;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: blue;
      background: red;
      margin: -3px 0;

      span {
        &.short {
          display: none;
        }

        &.long {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

This is caused when I account for the border and try to keep everything in line without changing the height. To make the border of the top and bottom `li` elements blend in with the border of the `ul`, I used the line of code `margin: -3px 0`. This is because the border width is `3px`.

My question is how do I make it so that the easing of the margin and border is even so the height of the `ul` remains stationary throughout the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **adding** the border on hover which changes the height of the `li`.

Instead, give it a default **transparent** border and just change the border color on hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 1vh;
}
.side-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: blue;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  width: 1cm !important;
}
.side-nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  width: 1cm;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.side-nav li span {
  white-space: pre;
}
.side-nav li span.short {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
.side-nav li span.long {
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
.side-nav li:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  right: 200%;
  width: 3cm;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-color: blue;
  background: red;
}
.side-nav li:hover span.short {
  display: none;
}
.side-nav li:hover span.long {
  display: block;
}
.side-nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="side-nav" class="side-nav" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="short">S</span><span class="long">Long</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="short">S</span><span class="long">Long</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="short">S</span><span class="long">Long</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="short">S</span><span class="long">Long</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="short">S</span><span class="long">Long</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mvpzf5Lf/6/)

Comment: Thanks. Mixing this with the `margin: -3px 0` worked great